# When was Superman first mentioned in Literature?

Tags: dc, superman

The character of Superman seems ubiquitous today as it found its way into popular culture. When was Superman first mentioned in Literature and what are his roots?

Comment: What do you mean by "in literature"? Are you referring to the first Superman comics, or to literary roots that led to the creation of Superman himself by Siegel and Shuster?

Comment: Or are you referring to the first time the character Superman was mentioned outside of comics in other literature?

Comment: @JackBNimble: Literature includes comics, doesn't it? The question asks for the first mention of the figure / it's origin.

Comment: This came up in the reopen review queue... I wanted to edit it to make it worthy of re-opening, but I can't quite figure out how. Bitmask, do you mean a non-uppercase-S superman? If so, I can help word this better, I think.

Comment: @JohnO: You're very welcome. I have to say I'm not that much adept in Superman canon --- I saw the three films when they came out but that's about it (so, I don't know what you mean by non-uppercase-S superman). I was really curious about where the figure we know from e.g. the first three Superman-films originates from. I realise this was probably a comic book. But which year? How does the "first" appearance of Superman differ from what we know today? And so on.

Comment: You don't count Nietsche, *Mencsh und Übermensch*?

Answer (score 5):

The concept of the super-man has been around actually since before the written word.  Modern incarnations tend to draw mostly from mythology and religious canon; think Hercules, demi-gods, Adam before the fall, Rasputin, etc.

Superman (with a capital 's') could only have appeared first in the DC comics, then later others would have written about the super-man using Superman as a reference.